# Connection was not established Xdebug 3 with PhpStorm timeout error

Tags: php, drupal, phpunit, xdebug, docksal

I need Xdebug to keep track of incoming data, where it goes, etc.
Since I run (raise up) the Drupal site using docksal, I set it up according to the instructions https://docs.docksal.io/tools/xdebug/#phpstorm

I wrote the command:

```
fin config set --env=local XDEBUG_ENABLED=1
```

And in the file `docksal-local.env` changed to:

```
XDEBUG_ENABLED="1"
```

I wrote the command:

```
fin project start
```

I checked Xdebug:

```
fin exec php-v | grep -i xdebug
```

And received:

```
with Xdebug v3.1.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans
```

I am running PHPUnit Kernel and Unir test, I put a breakpoint on some line.
I clicked the Start Listening for PHP Debug Connections button list.

I went to the site page in the browser, updated it and returned to PhpStorm but nothing happened. What do I need to do to make Xdebug work?

Getting this error :

```
[Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: 192.168.64.1:9000 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file looks like this:

**php.ini :**

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = php_xdebug-3.1.5-vc15-x86_64.dll
xdebug.mode = debug,develop
xdebug.discover_client_host = yes
xdebug.log_level = 0
xdebug.log = "%sprogdir%/userdata/temp/xdebug/log.txt"
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
```

**launch.json**

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9003,
        "env": {
            "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "log_level=7",
        }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply
But, I am doing it in Phpstorm and I haven't modified anything in php.ini. It is in read only mode. All the configuration are by default